# The Swiftest of Defeats

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

> The quadruped resigns.

*Short little puzzle that popped into my head.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Forfeit

Reasoning

> Forfeit sounds a bit like "four feet" - as in quadruped.